# matplotlib Histogram legend font family change

Tags: python, matplotlib

Very quick question. I would like to change the font family of a legend within the following:

```
ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize='xx-small', fontfamily=???)
```

However, I know that `fontfamily` is the wrong keyword argument. My question is, what is the right kwarg to do this?

I'm not sure what the right argument is, or if this is even possible without changing default rc parameters...

I have looked on stack overflow and on a host of other sites and help guides, but nothing specific to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legend has a keyword called `prop` (which is really for font properties ... why it's not fontprop or something like that I don't know) that you can use to specify font properties with a dictionary.  Your line of code would look something like this if you wanted, say, the serif family:

```
ax.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'family':'serif', 'size':'xx-small'})
```

Notice you have to move the size specification into the dictionary with the rest, `prop` will override `fontsize`.